# Import another Texture at runtime within THREE.JS and GLTF

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

I'm still pretty new at Three.JS, I'm pretty happy where I have gotten so far, but just need some help.

I have an GLTF object loaded into the scene, I want to be able to load different textures onto the object on the website by the user selecting a style, (like a customization feature).

Below is my code, at the moment it outputs nothing and I get the following error:

**In Chrome:**

> "TypeError: Cannot set property 'map' of undefined"

**In Firefox:**

> "TypeError: model.material is undefined"

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = textureLoader.load('../gtf/green/green.png');
texture.flipY = false;

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( '../gtf/Box.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    model = gltf.scene;
    scene.add( model );
});

model.material.map = texture;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The function `loader.load()` runs asynchronously and you don't have the `model` variable immediately set after you call it. So the solution you are looking for is to move the `model.material.map = texture;` inside the callback function, like this:

```
loader.load( '../gtf/Box.gltf', function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;
    texture.flipY = false; // for glTF models only
    model.material.map = texture; // <-- move here
    scene.add( model );
});
```

This will guarantee that you have a valid `model` object that you can use.

Comment: Hey Hugo, Thanks for that. 

I got it working, and pretty happy with it. 

I've posted a new question, below is the link, if you have any insight to that problem, that would be amazing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068620/create-an-array-of-meshes-from-object-three-js-and-gltf

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are running into is that the scene that you have assigned as `model` contains a lot more information than just the mesh and material information.  You will need to iterate over the scene object `model` in order to find the mesh, and then change the material accordingly.  While the initial data format that you are using is different, the answers you are looking for can be found in a previous post here:

[Change texture of loaded .obj in three.js at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324936/change-texture-of-loaded-obj-in-three-js-at-runtime)

**Edit:**
@HugoTeixeira is right that assignment of the texture needs to be moved into the callback function of `loader.load()` (sorry, I totally overlooked this previously), but the actual assignment `model.material.map = texture;` isn't going to work. You will still need to iterate over the `gltf.scene` object as mentioned above in order to find the mesh that you want to assign the texture to.

Comment: Thanks @jlcox5, 

Seems to make sense, and just got it working. 

Would you know, if its possible to apply a texture to a certain part of the model? 

So the GLTF is from Blender, could I apply a texture to one side? Or should I be using an .obj and .MTL file and using an array of objects?

Comment: Hey @TheGoldenD0nut, the [GLTF format](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/README.md) specifies that you can have multiple meshes per file. You should be able to find the specific mesh you want to change with the iteration mentioned above, and assign new textures individually. That said, how your model is organized will depend on its construction in Blender, and the exporter you used when creating the GLTF file to begin with. It's easy to open the .gltf file and look for the "meshes" entry in the JSON blob to get an idea. Issues like this will be present for most formats.