# Create an Array of Meshes from Object (THREE.JS and GLTF)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, blender, gltf

Below is my piece of code which loads a mesh onto the object. At the moment its traversing through the entire thing.

Current code:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( '../gtf/Box.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                model = gltf.scene;

                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        child.material.map = texture;
                    }
                } );

                scene.add( model);
            } );
```

How would I go about making an array of `children[]`? Each child will would then allow me to assign separate textures.

I have made the model in Blender with separate meshes and materials.

In THREE.JS, I want to be able to go:

```
children[0].material.map = blueTexture;

children[1].material.map = greenTexture;
```

etc

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do the following:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( '../gtf/Box.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
  model = gltf.scene;

  var children = []

  // Construct array of children during traversal of gltf object
  gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
      if ( child.isMesh ) {
          children.push(child)
      }
  } );

  // Assuming array length is 2 or more, and blueTexture/greenTexture are defined
  children[0].material.map = blueTexture;
  children[1].material.map = greenTexture;

  scene.add( model);
} );
```

Comment: Hey Dacre, exactly what I was looking for.
I will comment again letting you know if it worked 

Is there a call/function I could use to get the size of the array after the traverse?

Comment: children.length

Comment: Hey @TheGoldenD0nut glad I could help - yes, you could do this: `children.length` to get the size of the array once traversal is done. If you need to access this array outside of the `load()` handler, simply move the `var children = []` outside of that function. Hope this helps!